# Destiny 2 API Help {Javascript}

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I need help with the Destiny 2 / Bungie.net API. I am having trouble with getting stats of a destiny 2 player. I am using the npm package: [Click Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/destiny2) Heres my code:

```
destiny2.getProfile('Zyenax#1565', '4').then(data => console.log(data));
```

I have also tried using:

```
destiny2.getProfile('Zyenax', '4').then(data => console.log(data));
```

But for some reason, they don't want to pull up stats for PC users. They use Battle.net for their published software to run Destiny 2 through so I was thinking I need the battle.net tag in my name but that's not the case I don't think. I have also tried using this same code for getting Xbox 1 and Ps4 players stats and it works. I just can't get the pc one to work.

ERROR CODES:

```
(node:7100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'membershipId' of undefined
```

Comment: that is such a poorly written library!! if there's any errors, the author seems to misunderstand promises on every level!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you instantiated an object destiny2? Something like

```
var destiny2 = new Destiny({ /* options */ });
```

Can you show us your code?

Comment: I ended up making my own methods due to the lack of the authors horrible library explanation.

Comment: Its just that bad huh? Did you make it work? If yes, you can edit your question and put the code inside for people to see what needs to be done. Cheers